# Victory Chart - x-Axis label shorten, custom range and prevent overlapping

Tags: react-native, victory-charts

Using Victory Chart, I have created a simple BarChart. At the X-Axis, I have big number ranging from 500,000 to 3,000,000. Because the Chart is very narrow, the numbers at the X-Axis are overlapping. My Code looks like this:

```
   <VictoryChart>
      theme={VictoryTheme.material}
      <VictoryGroup
        height={chartHeight}
        offset={10}>
        <VictoryBar
          horizontal
          data={chart2}
          labels={d => d.y}
          labelComponent={<VictoryLabel dy={10} />}
        />
        <VictoryBar horizontal data={chart1} />
      </VictoryGroup>
    </VictoryChart>
```

1. I want to have the x-axis labels like that: 500,000 -> 500K.
2. Furthermore on the x-axis, I would like to have only 4-5 labels, which are always evenly spreed, so e.g. 0, 1000K, 2000K, 3000K, 4000K. If I have data which x-axis going to 1000K, separation would be 0, 250K, 500K, 750K, 1000K.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There's also a prop called `fixLabelOverlap` that you can pass in to the axis.

It is set to `false` by default.

https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/victory-axis#fixlabeloverlap

Comment: FixLabelOverlap hides some of the labels to make space if I'm correct. Right?

Answer (score 0):

Just add Padding to the group

https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/guides/layout

```
style={{
                data: { width: 3 },
                labels: { padding: -20 }
              }}
```